# css menu pop up position not showing all rows

Tags: html, css, menu, hover

I'm working on a responsive template which I downloaded. 
I custom coded the page via php, and my pages have more categories then the defualt template.

The issue is, the menu is disappearing when on the lower rows on the menu . The over effect only works on the top rows.
I assume the menu was built for only a few categories as you see on the default template.
I know little to nothing about the design css coding of the page.

what i forgot to clearly mention is that all the categories have a subcategorie. however the dropdown hover effect to show the subcategires only works on the 3 top rows of the menu. The lower rows of the menu also have subcategires however they do not show.

what edits do i have to make to the .css file to showup correctly for all rows?

reference links -- 
defualt template:   http://phantom-3.com/leoshop-pack/index.html
website in qustion: http://phantom-3.com/leo-automenu-tuneup.php?u=toys-r-us

any suggestions?

Comment: please try to post some code with the error

Comment: im not getting any errors.

Comment: post a fiddle where we can see the uncorrect behavior

Comment: what i forgot to clearly mention is that all the categories have a subcategorie. however the dropdown hover effect to show the subcategires only works on the 3 top rows of the menu. The lower rows of the menu also have subcategires however they do not show.

Answer (score 1):

In the second row of menu some additional styles has been added. You need to remove tha one. I am not sure how that added in your code. If you share proper HTML, JS and CSS then we can help you. Right now what i found is

```
 <div class="megapanel" style="display: none; opacity: 1;">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col1">
                        <div class="h_nav">
                            <h4>Computers/Tablets &amp; Networking</h4>
                            <ul><li><a href="leocat.php?c=162497&amp;u=toys-r-us">Monitors - Projectors &amp; Accs</a></li><li><a href="leocat.php?c=175672&amp;u=toys-r-us">Laptops &amp; Netbooks</a></li><li><a href="leocat.php?c=171485&amp;u=toys-r-us">iPads - Tablets &amp; eBook Readers</a></li><li><a href="leocat.php?c=176970&amp;u=toys-r-us">iPad/Tablet/eBook Accessories</a></li><li><a href="leocat.php?c=3676&amp;u=toys-r-us">Keyboards - Mice &amp; Pointing</a></li><li><a href="leocat.php?c=31530&amp;u=toys-r-us">Laptop &amp; Desktop Accessories</a></li><li><a href="leocat.php?c=31491&amp;u=toys-r-us">Cables &amp; Connectors</a></li><li><a href="leocat.php?c=171961&amp;u=toys-r-us">Printers - Scanners &amp; Supplies</a></li><li><a href="leocat.php?c=18793&amp;u=toys-r-us">Software</a></li><li><a href="leocat.php?c=175673&amp;u=toys-r-us">Computer Components &amp; Parts</a></li><li><a href="leocat.php?c=165&amp;u=toys-r-us">Drives - Storage &amp; Blank Media</a></li>                                    
                            </ul>   
                        </div>                          
                    </div>

                  </div>
                </div>
```

The above code should not have the inline property. It should like below.

```
 <div class="megapanel">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col1">
                        <div class="h_nav">
                            <h4>Computers/Tablets &amp; Networking</h4>
                            <ul><li><a href="leocat.php?c=162497&amp;u=toys-r-us">Monitors - Projectors &amp; Accs</a></li><li><a href="leocat.php?c=175672&amp;u=toys-r-us">Laptops &amp; Netbooks</a></li><li><a href="leocat.php?c=171485&amp;u=toys-r-us">iPads - Tablets &amp; eBook Readers</a></li><li><a href="leocat.php?c=176970&amp;u=toys-r-us">iPad/Tablet/eBook Accessories</a></li><li><a href="leocat.php?c=3676&amp;u=toys-r-us">Keyboards - Mice &amp; Pointing</a></li><li><a href="leocat.php?c=31530&amp;u=toys-r-us">Laptop &amp; Desktop Accessories</a></li><li><a href="leocat.php?c=31491&amp;u=toys-r-us">Cables &amp; Connectors</a></li><li><a href="leocat.php?c=171961&amp;u=toys-r-us">Printers - Scanners &amp; Supplies</a></li><li><a href="leocat.php?c=18793&amp;u=toys-r-us">Software</a></li><li><a href="leocat.php?c=175673&amp;u=toys-r-us">Computer Components &amp; Parts</a></li><li><a href="leocat.php?c=165&amp;u=toys-r-us">Drives - Storage &amp; Blank Media</a></li>                                    
                            </ul>   
                        </div>                          
                    </div>

                  </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: We cant give help to fix this issue until unless you share the actual code.

Comment: http://phantom-3.com/leoshop-pack/web/js/megamenu.js


http://phantom-3.com/leoshop-pack/web/css/megamenu.css
http://phantom-3.com/menucode.txt

Comment: phantom-3.com/menuhtml.txt

Comment: Your file have only 5 menu items. From where the remaining menu items are coming??

Comment: they are being generated in a loop in the php construct

Comment: I think im just going to purchase a menu script from code-canyon and change it to a vertical menu.